# How to use the vue-upload-drop-images component (Vue.js)

Tags: vuejs2

me, I want to use the vue-upload-drop-images component
of https://github.com/yudax42/vue-upload-drop-images. Since I couldn't find a demo on how to use it, I tried it on codepen.io. But I don't know why my project doesn't work. Can anyone help me with my mistake. Thank you
My codepen.io [https://codepen.io/Tin-Minh-the-animator/pen/QWJveKr](https://stackoverflow.com)

https://github.com/yudax42/vue-upload-drop-images | vue2.js